# How to remove or hide Browse By Country of Manufacture in products page left bar?

Tags: products, product-list, products-view

I am using Gocamping Magebuzz theme (Magento 1.9.1) with Manufacture addon . I am trying to hide the browse by --> Country of Manufacture . It is still showing. Suggest how to remove or hide. I have disabled Magebuzz_Manufacturer and tried. No improvement.

[image: Browse By Country of Manufacture]

Comment: Hi John, did you already try to check Magebuzz support sources or contact them? I don't think that you will have any luck here on Magento SE with such a specific theme bound question... Or you should post some code examples of how the theme adds this feature into Magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Country of Manufacture" is one of Magento's default product attribute which you can choose not to display on the frontend layered navigation.

Follow the below steps to hide it from the frontend.

```
    Go to Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes.
    Search for "country_of_manufacture" in the Attribute Code column.
    Open the attribute detail page and in the Frontend Properties, choose NO in "Use In Layered Navigation".
    Save the attribute, clear indexes and cache.
```

Now, the attribute won't be displayed anymore on the frontend.